# Is there a hotkey to navigate messages in an email thread in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hotkeys

In Outlook message threads, there are links in the courner that let you jump to different messages in the thread (First, Previous, Next, Last). Is there a hotkey to use these links without clicking on them?
[image: Message jump links]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As an alternative, you can configure Outlook to let you press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to navigate/read an entire message thread:

1. Open Outlook's Options
2. In the **Mail** group scroll down to the *Outlook panes* section and click **Reading Pane...**
3. Select the option **Single key reading using space bar**

With this enabled, while reading a message in the Reading Pane, press <kbd>Space</kbd> repeatedly to scroll through the message, one page at a time.

Comment: Could you add a few words on how exactly the space bar is used to this end? Great to know how to turn it on, better to also know how to use it.

Comment: @High Great suggestion. Answer updated.